# Python subprocess time calls /usr/bin/time instead of keyword

Tags: python, linux, time, terminal, subprocess

I'm trying to get the time of a process, and when I use the keyword time in the shell, I get a nicer output as:

```
real    0m0,430s
user    0m0,147s
sys     0m0,076s
```

Instead of the `/usr/bin/time` which gives a different output. When I try to run it through python's subprocess library with `subprocess.call('time command args',shell=True)` it gives me the /usr/bin/time instead of the keyword. How can I use the keyword function as opposed to the current one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell=True` causes `subprocess` to use `/bin/sh`, not `bash`. You need the `executable` argument as well

```
subprocess.call('time command args', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Adjust the path to `bash` as necessary.